# "ImportError: No module named requests" in crontab Python script

Tags: python, python-3.x, cron

I'm trying to set up a Python script in crontab. I have the following:

`0-59 * * * * python ~/PycharmProjects/dailySearch.py trees >> ~/woah.log 2>&1`

In my log file I'm getting `ImportError: No module named requests`. I've scoured other SO questions and tried various suggestions with no success.

When I run the script in my IDLE, `sys.version` shows my version as `3.7.1 (default, Dec 14 2018, 13:28:58)`

I have two Python versions installed and though I'm running python3 (3.7.1), I'm not sure that my I have requests and pip installed where it should be as well

python3 is at: `/Users/jaai/anaconda3/bin/python3`

pip3: `/Users/jaai/anaconda3/bin/pip3`

And to confirm I'm installing requests using pip3, I ran `sudo pip3 install requests` with the following:

```
Requirement already satisfied: requests in /Users/jaai/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages (2.22.0)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3!=1.25.0,!=1.25.1,<1.26,>=1.21.1 in /Users/jaai/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from requests) (1.24.1)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2017.4.17 in /Users/jaai/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from requests) (2018.11.29)
Requirement already satisfied: chardet<3.1.0,>=3.0.2 in /Users/jaai/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from requests) (3.0.4)
Requirement already satisfied: idna<2.9,>=2.5 in /Users/jaai/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from requests) (2.8)
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A couple of things could be the culprit, but just to make sure the interpreter you run is the same cron is using, make sure you include the full path to python3, i.e.

```
0-59 * * * * /Users/jaai/anaconda3/bin/python3/python ~/PycharmProjects/dailySearch.py trees >> ~/woah.log 2>&1
```

If the problem persists then maybe you should look into setting the PYTHONPATH environment variable for cron so that it matches the one set for your shell.

Comment: Your solution worked, thanks. I'm curious as to why it didn't work. I forgot to mention that I've tried setting an alias (`alias python=/Users/jaai/anaconda3/bin/python3`). Also if I just run `python` in the terminal I can confirm it's version 3.7.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue on Ubuntu 18.04 and using the explicit path in the crontab did not work. For some reason, cron did not work and sudo from my account did work. I would have assumed they would be the same but alas, they were not. I came to the conclusion that it was an environment variable issue.

For me the fix was to have crontab call a shell script which then executes the python script. Also had to set *HOME* and *PYTHONPATH* environment variables:

crontab:

```
# Execute shell script and pipe stdout and stderr to a log file
# Which will enable you to see what's going on
* * * * * <your_path>/yourscript.sh  >> <your_path>yourscript_cron.log 2>&1
```

yourscript.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo yourscript.sh called: `date`
HOME=<your_home_dir>
PYTHONPATH=<path_to_dist_packages>
cd <path_to_your_python_script>
<python_executable> ./<your_python_script> 2>&1 1>/dev/null
```

Funny enough, this shell wrapper method is the way I settled on for scheduled tasks on windows in the past as it gives you the best debugging possible and flexibility.

Hope this helps someone else.

Comment: Just confirmed it was the HOME environment variable which was different between the cron and using sudo. When I ran the follow it fialed just like cron: sudo bash -c "HOME=FOO;python3 -c \"import psutil\"" .