# crontab error "ImportError: No module named request" python runs OK in terminal - fails in crontab

Tags: python-requests, cron, python-3.6

I am having difficulty in a running python script that calls module "requests" in crontab. This was fine a few days ago and then I had to change my authentication for Google (to send emails), then "requests" stopped working in crontab. The python script runs fine in a terminal but will not execute in crontab. "requests" is available and when I type "pip3 show requests" the following is displayed (note I replaced my user name with "user"):

```
$pip3 show requests

Name: requests
Version: 2.27.1
Summary: Python HTTP for Humans.
Home-page: https://requests.readthedocs.io
Author: Kenneth Reitz
Author-email: me@kennethreitz.org
License: Apache 2.0
Location: /home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages
Requires: certifi, idna, urllib3, charset-normalizer
```

A simplified version of the python file I would like to execute in crontab is:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python...
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import requests
print ('End of code')
```

The file ***test_request.py*** executes fine in a terminal.

I created a bash script called ***test_request.sh*** based on directions from this stack overflow page:

["ImportError: No module named requests" in crontab Python script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58984276/importerror-no-module-named-requests-in-crontab-python-script)

That bash script is this:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo test_request.sh called: `date`
HOME=/home/user/
PYTHONPATH=/home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages
cd /home/user/Documents/bjg_code/
python ./test_request.py  2>&1 1>/dev/null
```

When I try to run the bash script in a terminal or in crontab I receive this error:

```
$bash test_request.sh 

test_request.sh called: Sat Jun 11 14:18:46 EDT 2022
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./test_request.py", line 4, in <module>
    import requests
ImportError: No module named requests
```

Any advice would be welcomed and appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Probably you are using /etc/crontab instead of crontab -e as current user

Comment: Telinov, how do I tell the difference? I edit crontab by typing $crontab -e. How would I check /etc/crontab? Thank you.